# Defining operator<< Inside Class

Tags: c++, oop, class, operator-overloading, friend-function

Consider the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    template <typename Datatype>
    friend MyClass& operator<<(MyClass& MyClassReference, Datatype SomeData);
    // ...
};

template <typename Datatype>
MyClass& operator<<(MyClass& MyClassReference, Datatype SomeData)
{
    // ...
}
```

How can I define `operator<<` *inside* the class, rather than as a friend function?  Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...

    public:

    template <typename Datatype>
    MyCLass& operator<<(MyClass& MyClassReference, Datatype SomeData)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

The above code produces compilation errors because it accepts two arguments.  Removing the `MyClassReference` argument fixes the errors, but I have code that relies on that argument.  Is `MyClassReference` just the equivalent of `*this`?

Comment: Is `MyClass` a template that takes a `DataType` type argument?

Comment: @David No; `Datatype` was used in lieu of an actual type for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @Maxpm: So why did you add the `template` in what seems to be a definition? You are declaring a friend function, but defining a template which is a different beast and as such not a friend.

Comment: @David So the inserter operator can take input of any type.

Comment: Then befriend the template, not a function. `template <typename T> void foo( T );` is a template, `void foo( int );` is a function, `f(1)` is a call to the non-template function and `f<int>(5)` is a call to the templated function. They are different things, so you cannot befriend one and expect the other to have access. I have added an answer below. If that is not clear enough, tell me and I will try to extend it.

Comment: @David Thank you.  I've corrected my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
template <typename Datatype> MyClass& operator<<(MyClass& MyClassReference, Datatype SomeData);
```

inside of the class. It is a method of the class `MyClass`. Non-static methods have an implicit parameter called the `this` pointer. The `this` pointer is a pointer to the object the method was called on. You do not need the `MyClassReference` parameter because the `this` pointer fulfills that purpose.

Change that method declaration to

```
template <typename Datatype> MyClass& operator<<(Datatype SomeData);
```

.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is good idea, but yes -- when you define `operator<<` as a member function, `*this` will essentially equivalent to the first parameter you've defined in your operator.

Comment: -1 Incorrect. `operator<<` is not only for streams. It is simply an operator. He is effectively writing an insertion operator for his class, to insert object of type `Datatype` into an object of class `MyClass`.

Comment: @Sion Sheevok: Yes - I realized what he was after and was editing before you commented (it only got posted to start with by accident).

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
    template <typename Datatype>
    friend MyClass& operator<<(MyClass& MyClassReference, Datatype SomeData) 
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```